# How to add profiles to default maven goals in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am using Maven inside Eclipse to build and deploy code.

When choosing `{Context Menu} > Run As`, several Maven goals appear as follows:

[image: Eclipse Run As Context Menu]

I understand that if I want to create a custom build configuration, I would click "Run Configurations..." to create a custom configuration.

However, there seems to be no way to modify the configurations that appear conveniently on the menu.  For instance, you can't add a profile to #7 "Maven install".  The result is tedious, because you have click about 5 times to launch the build.

Is there any way to add profiles or additional goals to #7 "Maven install" build or add custom configurations to the context menu?

Is there a way to launch a specific build configuration with a keyboard combination?

I have tried IntelliJ and NetBeans and the Maven integration in all of them seems confusing trying to differentiate between basic Maven goals and the more realistic custom combination of goals and profiles.

Comment: Would setting one of the profiles as default in the pom work for you, or do you have a specific need? Also, you can setup a run configuration, and then choose it as a favourite from the "down arrow on the right of the green Run button" on your toolbar :)

Comment: Ha, OK.  I looked right past that green play button thinking it was some sort of local debugging thing. That is sufficient. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. The debug menu is a similar concept but it has a "bug icon". I'll make a couple of screenshots to better explain what I meant above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Select "Maven build..." from the menu and create the configuration

[image: Create configuration]

2. Add it to the favourites for later use / launch the build

[image: Add it to favourites for later use]

Comment: That only affects the drop down from the top nav, but not the submenu on the context menu from a POM file.