# How to add maven goals in Eclipse for all Maven projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I know how to add a [Maven goal to a Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820945/how-to-add-profiles-to-default-maven-goals-in-eclipse) project in Eclipse. How can I add a Maven goal e.g.:

```
mvn install -DskipTests
```

for all my Maven projects in Eclipse?

Comment: First why do you need `install`? And why skipping the tests?

Comment: It was just an example. I also need other goals like `checkstyle:check`, `dependency:copy-dependencies` or something else.

Comment: In Eclipse, you can have launch configs. We wrote a script that allows you to add common goals as launch configs to a project.

Comment: To be honest why do you need such goals? `checkstyle:check` should be part of the build and not called manually via goal and even `dependency:copy-dependencies` ?

Comment: Why does that matter which goal it is?

Comment: @khmarbaise The examples maybe not good, but the general problem remains. We also need goals like `dependency:analyze`, `versions:update-parent`, `versions:use-releases` which cannot be included into the build.